# Accessing D-Link stack members separately

Tags: stacking

I have a D-Link switch stack, can not figure out how to fore needed switch to became a master using

```
config stacking force_master_role
```

I simply do not get what will this command to and the D-Link's documentation is not helpful, so I wonder if there is a way to access stack member units separately and fire this command to see if the switch becoming the master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is done by setting the unit priority (lowest number becomes master) see info here

http://www.dlink.com/it/it/-/media/business_products/dgs/dgs-3420/manual/dgs_3420_series_r150_cli_reference_guide.pdf

Comment: Please consider adding relevant details to this post, so it remains useful even when the linked document is removed.